# How tocomplete this scriptl?

Tags: 3dsmax

I’m a newbie in using MAX script, can anyone help me write a script to select in SME all material have name contain a string. Example : i have some material in SME name : #1 wood, #2 wood, old wood, #1 steel, #2 steel, old steel … and I want seclect all material have name contain “wood” : #1 wood, #2 wood, old wood.

Thank for any help !

Comment: Is this just asking how to do some homework?